# Error : Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<Integer> to ArrayList<Integer>

Tags: java, casting, compiler-errors

```java
package set01;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DFTList {
    static List<Integer>[]   list;
    static boolean[] visited;
    
    public DFTList(int nodes) {
        list = new ArrayList[nodes];
        visited = new boolean[nodes];
        for(int i=0;i<nodes;i++) {
           list[i] = new ArrayList<>();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter no. of nodes : ");
        int nodes = scan.nextInt();
        DFTList obj = new DFTList(nodes);
        System.out.println("Enter no.of vertex : ");
        int vertex = scan.nextInt();
        
        
        for(int i=0;i<vertex;i++) {
            int v1 = scan.nextInt();
            int v2 = scan.nextInt();
            list[v1].add(v2);
            list[v2].add(v1);
        }
        
        solve(0);
    }
    
    public static void solve(int a) {
        visited[a] = true;
        ArrayList<Integer> l = list[a];
    }

}
```

In the above code snippet, At the `DFTList` constructor, I have inserted `ArrayList` object at all the indices of the array. But when I try to retrieve the same object at the **`solve` method** and store it under the **same reference**, I encountered an error stating that "Type mismatch: cannot convert from List to ArrayList". Why does this error occur?

Comment: As an aside, setting static fields each time a new instance is created (in the constructor) means that each new instance will overwrite the fields used by the previous instance.  To fix this, the fields and `solve` method should be made non-static.  Then all operations would be made on the instance, rather than the static methods: `DFTList obj = new DFTList(nodes); ... obj.list[v1].add(v2); obj.list[v2].add(v1); ... obj.solve(0);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `list` variable is a `List<Integer>[]`, which means that any type of `List` (`ArrayList`, `LinkedList`, etc.) could be stored in it.  When retrieving an element from this list, all the Java compiler knows is that it's some type of `List`; it doesn't know the specific type of `List` (even though you as the programmer know that you're only storing `ArrayList` items in the array).  Therefore, `ArrayList<Integer> l = list[a]` is a compilation failure because the compiler can't guarantee that the element retrieved from the array is an `ArrayList` and not a different `List` type.

There are a few ways to address this issue.  Assuming you wanted to keep `list` as an array, the most idiomatic approach would be to change its type to `List<Integer>[]` instead of `ArrayList<Integer>[]`.  Since you are not using any methods or other API specific to `ArrayList`, the `List` interface is a better choice for this type.

```java
    public static void solve(int a) {
        visited[a] = true;
        List<Integer> l = list[a];
    }
```

Another, less idiomatic approach would be to change the type of the `list` variable from `List<Integer>[]` to `ArrayList<Integer>[]`.  This change would cause your variable assignment to work as already written.

```java
public class DFTList {
    static ArrayList<Integer>[] list;
    ...
}
```

The final approach you could use when you have an array of the interface type (`List<Integer>` in this case) would be to cast the element to the concrete type when assigning it to the variable.  This is basically telling the compiler that you as the developer know the element is of that subtype, so even though it cannot guarantee the assignment, it will allow it to happen.  This approach defers the type checking — ensuring the `List` is the `ArrayList` subtype — until the code is actually run (at runtime).  If the stored element is a subtype other than `ArrayList` when the code is run (e.g. if it's a `LinkedList`), then Java will throw a [ClassCastException](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ClassCastException.html) since the assignment to `ArrayList` cannot happen.

Casting like this is not ideal, as it removes guarantees by the compiler that all types being used are guaranteed to be valid at runtime.  However, there are times where it is necessary and appropriate.

```java
    public static void solve(int a) {
        visited[a] = true;
        ArrayList<Integer> l = (ArrayList<Integer>) list[a];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`list` is declared as a `List<Integer>[]` (read: an array of Lists of Integers). The fact that the value in each element is actually an `ArrayList` is inconsequential - as far as the compiler is concerned, every element is a `List`.

You could either explicitly downcast the array access:

```
ArrayList<Integer> l = (ArrayList<Integer>)list[a];
```

Or, more idiomatically, if you aren't relying on any specific method `ArrayList` has that isn't present in the `List` interface, you could declare `l` as a `List<Integer>`:

```
List<Integer> l = list[a];
```

Comment: (read: an array of Lists of Integers) it is right, but List is just an interface actual implementations done in  ArrayList/LinkedList, right! so why can't I use ArrayList<Integer> l = list[a]; I'm still confused, If possible give some extra explanations/Examples. And thanks for your answer!!

Answer (score 0):

you are mixing C++ with Java!!

check the following reproducable code:

```
    public class DFTList {
    static List<Integer>[]   list;
    static boolean[] visited;
    
    public DFTList(int nodes) {
        list = new ArrayList[nodes];
        visited = new boolean[nodes];
        for(int i=0;i<nodes;i++) {
           list[i] = new ArrayList<>();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter no. of nodes : ");
        int nodes = scan.nextInt();
        DFTList obj = new DFTList(nodes);
        System.out.println("Enter no.of vertex : ");
        int vertex = scan.nextInt();
        
        
        for(int i=0;i<vertex;i++) {
            int v1 = scan.nextInt();
            int v2 = scan.nextInt();
            list[v1].add(v2);
            list[v2].add(v1);
        }
        
        solve(0);
    }
    
    public static void solve(int a) {
        visited[a] = true;
        List<Integer> l = list[a];
    }    
}
```

### Note 0

there is no `pointer` like concept in java therefore following snippet gives you compile time error:

```
 * list[i] = new ArrayList<>();
```

### Note 1

you are assigning `List` interface to `l` type therefore use below syntax.

```
   List<Integer> l = list[a];
```

Comment: Sorry brother, mistake is mine, I have included (*) to highlight and didn't realize the counter part that people might think it is a pointer. Now, I edited the post.